# What are the benefits in difference methods of CRUD operations?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

When performing the CRUD operations, we can execute it with `form` as follows:

```
      <form action="/todo/<%= todos[i]._id %>?_method=DELETE" method="POST">
           <button>x</button>
      </form>
```

And the controller as follows:

```
app.delete('/todo/:id', (req, res) => {
    Todo.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id, (err) => {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.redirect('/todo');
        }
    });
});
```

Or we can perform it using jQuery as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('form').on('submit', function(){

    var item = $('form input');
    var todo = {item: item.val()};

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/todo',
      data: todo,
      success: function(data){
        //do something with the data via front-end framework
        location.reload();
      }
    });

    return false;
  });
});
```

What is the difference between the two methods? (ignoring that one is to perform 'delete' and the other is to 'post') Some say the latter is more secure than the former, but could not find any literature regarding it.

Comment: "Some say the latter is more secure than the former" - yeah, that's nonsense. I'd like to see the reasoning behind that assertion.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Are there any notable difference between the two methods? The following link is where the person briefly mentions this point, although he doesn't provide any explanation https://youtu.be/aZ16pkrMkZE?t=875

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The following link is where the person briefly mentions this point [about ajax request being more secure], although he doesn't provide any explanation youtu.be/aZ16pkrMkZE?t=875

He's talking about something else entirely. Performing a DELETE request via ajax and deleting objects in your app via clicking a simple link (which would result in a GET request).

The latter is not only against conventions (GET requests should not change data), it's also... not insecure, but "dangerous". Imagine that google crawler visits your site and follows every link. Puff, all your deletable objects are gone.

And in some cases it can be insecure too. Imagine that in order to create/update/delete objects you need to authenticate user somehow. Say, with an auth token. Since it's a plain link and a GET request, the token must go to the query string. This way, it'll be exposed for everyone to see, cached in every caching proxy and stored for eternity in traffic logs. Not very secure.